# Have a paper js file that can be imported as a module

Tags: javascript, html, module, paperjs

I am making a game and I would like to have my code split into two files. One, an ordinary javascript file for the gameplay, the other a paperscript file for all the graphics. I want to call functions from the paperscript file from the main file, but as far as I can see it needs to be loaded with `type="module"` for me to be able to call functions, but it also needs to be loaded with `type="text/paperscript"` for it to work as paperscript.
If there is annother way to call functions from a different file I would like to hear about it, or if there is a way to include both `type="module"` and `type="text/paperscript"` in the same script element.

If this is not possible I know I could use javascript not paperscript but I would rather not because all the examples I have seen are using paperscript

Comment: you can `use javascript directly`: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

Comment: I know but I would prefer to use paperscript because that is what most of the tutorials are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do what I want and I feel very stupid now. I learned python and am new to javascript and didn't realise that you could just call functions from other files, in python you can only do this by using modules.

Here I can declare a variable as `window.<myVariableName>` in paperscript to be able to access it from raw javascript.